# What was Mizuki writing on her PC in the movie "Confessions"?

Tags: confessions

In "Confessions" by Tetsuya Nakashima, what was Mizuki writing on her laptop before getting whacked?

Comment: Meaning you want a translation of it or you just generally want to know what she was writing about? If you want a translation, you're going to need to post an image at the very least.

Comment: You are right. For the moment, as I'm not able to provide an image for that particolar scene, I'd like to know the general meaning. As soon as I'll have time to search for it on my blu, I'll post it here

Comment: @ed0, I think it was just a personal blog where she fantasized about being like the Lunacy girl. She never let anyone read it.